# Copy-Item path error

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of files in one parent folder with many subfolders.  I have a file containing the paths to the specific files I need copied to a destination folder.

To work out the command syntax I created a `c:\powershellplay` folder with a Source and a Dest folder and myfile.txt inside which contains the files I am testing with as below.

```
c:\powershellplay\source\1.txt
c:\powershellplay\source\2.txt
c:\powershellplay\source\3.txt
```

My command is

```
Get-Content c:\powershellplay\myfile.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "c:\powershellplay\dest"
}
```

I get the error

```
Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:73
+ Get-content c:\powershellplay\myfile.txt|Foreach-Object{copy-item -path $_.FullN ...
+                                                                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

What's wrong with the `$_.FullName`?

Comment: `Get-Content` return `[System.String]` not `[System.IO.FileInfo]`, and `[System.String]` does not have `FullName` property.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm quite new to power shell, how would you go about copying the files?  If it's relevant, I'm testing with 3 files.  I'll eventually need to use the command to copy a few hundred files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PetSerAl is correct in his comment.  If you look at the help on the Copy-Item -Path parameter you will see this:

```
Get-Help Copy-Item -Parameter Path

-Path <String[]>
    Specifies the path to the items to copy.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

The two important bits are the type `String[]` and `Accept pipeline input`.  Don't worry about passing in a single string as PowerShell will promote that to a one element string array as necessary.  The pipeline input info tells us it accepts input objects `ByValue` and `ByPropertyName` i.e. object's with a property name that corresponds to this parameter's name. It turns out PowerShell also will match up properties to any parameter alias and `PSPath` is an alias for the `LiteralPath` parameter.  This how you can pass FileInfo objects that Get-ChildItem outputs directly into Copy-Item (and many other commands that take a Path/LiteralPath).

In your case you can rely on `ByValue` and Copy-Item will use the strings you pass in directly e.g.:

```
Get-Content C:\powershellplay\myfile.txt | ? {![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} | 
    Copy-Item -Dest c:\powershellplay\dest
```

The `?{![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}` pipeline stage will filter out any empty or whitespace only lines that happen to be in the file.

Comment: This worked on my laptop, but when I ran it on my desktop at work, I got the following error.  'Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'.
At line:1 char:68
+ Get-Content C:\dest\filelist.txt | ? {![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace <<<< ($_)} | Copy-Item -Dest C:\Dest
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IsNullOrWhiteSpace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound'

Comment: Which version of PowerShell/.NET?  I think that was intro'd in .NET 4.   If you are confident you have no blank (or whitespace only lines), just remove that whole stage of the pipeline.

Comment: I know my workbox is .NET 4.5.2, how do I determine the version of powershell.  Also, it worked as ' Get-Content C:\dest\filelist.txt  | Copy-Item -Dest C:\Dest'  I appreciate the help.

Comment: $PSVersionTable will tell you.  If you don't have that variable, you're on PS v1 with .NET 2/3/3.5.  Also, you could change to `?{$_ -match '^\S+$'}` and that should work on all versions of PS.

Comment: $PSVersionTable returns 'Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1'

Comment: As I suspected.  Use `? {$_ -match '^\S+$'}` instead.